# ¿Cómo corregir este problema con la expresión regular?

Tags: sql

Estoy creando una base de datos en PGadmin con SQL y estoy intentando hacer crear un check para uno de los valores , pero no hay manera de que me lo valida a la hora de cargar los datos:

```
CREATE TABLE AEROPUERTO (
    ID_AEROPUERTO VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE_AEROPUERTO VARCHAR(120)NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE AEROPUERTO ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ID_AEROPUERTO CHECK (ID_AEROPUERTO = '[1-9][A-Z]{2}' );


INSERT INTO AEROPUERTO (ID_AEROPUERTO,NOMBRE_AEROPUERTO)
VALUES('1AZ','Josep Tarradellas El Prat');
```

lo que me indica es :

> ERROR:  el nuevo registro para la relación «aeropuerto» viola la restricción «check» «ck_id_aeropuerto»
> DETAIL:  La fila que falla contiene (1AB, Josep Tarradellas El Prat).
> Estado SQL: 23514

Pero no acabo de localizar donde esta el error.

gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vos como lees esa regexp?? y que base de datos estas usando? eso es super importante!

Comment: PGAdmin es el cliente. Cuál es la base de datos? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

por lo que pude observar el tema está en la estructura de la expresión regular.

hice unos pequeños cambios modificando la expresión regular y usando el **igual** por **LIKE**.

```
CREATE TABLE AEROPUERTO (
    ID_AEROPUERTO VARCHAR(3) CHECK (ID_AEROPUERTO LIKE '[0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]') PRIMARY KEY ,
    NOMBRE_AEROPUERTO VARCHAR(120)NOT NULL
)
```